# Use SNI with Undertow to add multiple domains under one IP

Tags: https, sni, undertow

Does Undertow support SNI? In other words, can I run https on multiple domains/certificates on a single IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undertow 1.3 and below do not support SNI. I'm guessing 1.4 won't either.

[There is a JIRA feature request for it.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-750)